# WP Как найти длину объекту если он ещё не задан?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть некий параметр `$p = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_key', true);` он должен стать типом 'object' когда пользователь нажмет кнопку на сайте, но пока этого не произошло в базе данных такого значения нет.

Как правильно подставить 0 для массива которого ещё не существует ?

```
<?php

$p = null;
$cp = count($p);
if( empty($cp) ) $cp = (int)0;

echo '<p>Количество кликов'.$p.'</p>';
```

вот [код](https://onlinephp.io/c/5dd89) Согласно документации [count](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.count.php) вернуть 0, но для массива или объекта. А как быть что б для `count($p)` возвращало 0 ?

Comment: `is_countable($p) ? count($p) : 0;` так?

Comment: Спасибо, Сработало. Главное не ставить `$p = (array) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_key', true);`